# PhoneGap 2.5 InAppBrowser NullReferenceException on Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, cordova

When trying to launch the InAppBrowser with PhoneGap 2.5 on Windows Phone, like so:

```
window.open(url, '_blank', 'location=yes');
```

a NullReferenceException occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [Rohit's solution at the Google Groups discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/phonegap/9Zpayg_L8f8), the solution is to comment out the line of code causing the NullReferenceException in the InAppBrowser.cs file, this one:

```
WebBrowser br = (page.FindName("CordovaView") as CordovaView).Browser;
```